# date Not null , error ora_01758

Tags: oracle

why I am getting this error ? 
In the table DDL I only have 2 columns , id (number) and name (varchar)

> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD SUSPEND date NOT NULL

> ORA-01758: table must be empty to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column
> ORA-06512: at line 7

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ORA-01758: **table must be empty** to add mandatory (NOT NULL) column ORA-06512: at line 7

And *is* your table empty? I think not.

There's probably a way around this involving adding the column as nullable, then populating every row with a non-NULL value, the altering the column to be `not null`.

Alternatively, since the problem is that these current rows will be given NULL as a default value, and the column is not allowed to be NULL, you can also get around it with a default value. From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.3.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html):

> However, a column with a NOT NULL constraint can be added to an existing table if you give a default value; otherwise, an exception is thrown when the ALTER TABLE statement is executed.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8655c/4), how you could do it

Answer (score 1):

Would a date in the future be acceptable as a temporary default?  If so, this would work:

ALTER TABLE MYTABLE  ADD (SUSPEND_DATE  DATE  DEFAULT(TO_DATE('21000101', 'YYYYMMDD'))
CONSTRAINT SUSPEND_DATE_NOT_NULL NOT NULL);

Answer (score 0):

If table already contain the records then table won't allowes to add "Not null" column.
If you need same then set default value for the column or truncate the table then try.

Comment: I agreed , but your requirement is not nullable column , so you have two option , you can truncate table or allow null values for existing record.. chice is yours..